# How to display the database content in browser in some format?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

My node.js code :

```
http.createServer(function (request, response)
{
    console.log('Creating the http server');
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM navd_compare LIMIT 100', function(err, rows, fields)
   {
        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
        console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

        response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
        response.end();
    });

}).listen(8084);
```

Comment: whats the problem?
first dont use .end twice

Comment: where/how is defined `connection` ?

Comment: In browser i am getting JSON output, but i want it in table. How to retrieve each row data rom database ? and convert it into js object and print it in browser

Comment: var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'tas123',
    database: 'navd'
});
connection

Comment: just use any view engine  like ejs ,jade or handle bar for that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write minimum code on the server you can use **Express**. For example:

```
var app = express();

app.route('/data')
.get(function(req, res, next) {
  /*your sql query*/
  res.json(result);
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

After this you can request your route on client with **AJAX**. Here is an example with `Fetch API`:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/data").then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
  /* here is your data */
})
```